# i am trying to insert collection object in db using saveOrUpdateAll() with hibernate. then i am getting UncategorizedSQLException)

Tags: java, hibernate

```
billSubmissionBean.setMasterProviderId(String.valueOf(masterProvider.getMasterProviderId()));
        masterBill.setMasterProvider(masterProvider);
        masterBill.setTransactionType(transactionType);
        billSubmissionDao.save(masterBill, MasterBill.class);

        BillSubmission billSubmission = getBillSubmissionFromBean(billSubmissionBean, user);
        billSubmission.setMasterBill(masterBill);
        billSubmission.setBillSubmissionNumber(masterBill.getBillSubmissionNumber());
        billSubmission.setMasterProviderId(masterProvider.getMasterProviderId());
        billSubmission.setTransactionType(transactionType);

        billSubmission.setApiFlg(Boolean.TRUE);
        if(StringUtils.strToBoolean(billSubmissionBean.getGenerateBillDocument())) {
            billSubmission.setBillDocumentFlg(Boolean.TRUE);
        }
        billSubmissionDao.save(billSubmission, BillSubmission.class);

        List<BillingServiceBean> billingServicesList = billSubmissionBean.getServices();
        if(billingServicesList != null) {
            List<BillService> billServicesList = new ArrayList<BillService>();
            for (BillingServiceBean billServiceBean : billingServicesList) {
                BillService billService = getBillServiceFromBillServiceBean(billServiceBean, user, billSubmissionBean.getGenerateBillDocument());
                billService.setBillSubmission(billSubmission);
                billServicesList.add(billService);
            }
            log.info("Bill services size : " + billServicesList.size());
            if(billingServicesList.size() > 0) {
                billSubmissionDao.saveOrUpdateAll(billServicesList);
```

// **At This location **

> org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate
>   flushing: could not insert: [gov.nysif.model.BillService];
>   uncategorized SQLException for SQL [insert into nysif.bill_service
>   (bill_submission_id, service_place, service_procedure,
>   service_modifiers, dx_pointer, service_days, billed_amount,
>   service_ndc, service_ndc_qty, anesthesia_start, anesthesia_end,
>   revenue_code, dos_from_dt, dos_to_dt, created_dt, created_user,
>   modified_dt, modified_user, non_covered_charges, bill_service_id)
>   values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)];
>   SQL state [55000]; error code [0]; This statement has been closed.;
>   nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This statement
>   has been closed.          }       }

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the exception you can see you get an `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This statement has been closed.` exception.

I guess your connection is a bit inactive in the time of being and it gets closed. Try to get to tune those values. For example with `minimumIdle`
and/or `connectionTimeout`.

Alternatively it can be because of your `transactionType` what means that the first call of `billSubmissionDao.save(billSubmission, BillSubmission.class);` closes the transaction and the call to `billSubmissionDao.saveOrUpdateAll(billServicesList);` has no active transaction and it throws you this error.

Comment: initialSize="5"
  maxActive="150" 
  minIdle="0"
  maxIdle="8" 
  defaultAutoCommit="false"
  defaultTransactionIsolation="-1" 
  maxWait="3000" 
  timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="1000"
  minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="1000"
  testOnBorrow="true" 
  testOnReturn="false"
  testWhileIdle="false" 
  removeAbandoned="true"
  removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
  logAbandoned="true"
  poolPreparedStatements="true" 
  maxOpenPreparedStatements="40"

Comment: please guide me according to given connection pooling

Comment: one more doubt, i am getting this exception randomly but not continuously, if exception occurred it is coming at  billSubmissionDao.saveOrUpdateAll(billServicesList);  but not at   billSubmissionDao.save(billSubmission, BillSubmission.class) what is the reason

Comment: in windows o.s i am not getting any exception, this exception occurring in production server only which is linux . please guide